# Jar file don't works like in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I've got some problem with my jar file. When I run project in NetBeans everything works fine. But when I run it as a jar file I've got Null Pointer Exception in this function:

```
public void setBg(int w, int h){

    BufferedImage bgg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = bgg.getGraphics();
    for(int i = 0; i < board.getHeight(); ++i){
                for(int j = 0; j < board.getWidth(); ++j){
                    g.drawImage(board.getBoardElement(j, i).getImage().getScaledInstance(element_w, element_h, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), ((j*element_w)), ((i*element_h)), this);
                System.out.println(j+" "+i);
                }
            }

    bg=bgg; //it's important to not blinkink map while it's drawing
}
```

Everytime when I run application by jar variables i and j has different values when NullPointerException occurs. What could be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating the method in a try-catch and printing out a stack trace for the exception?

Comment: Add your pictures to src folder, then make clean&build and try again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by adding in some debug statements (`System.out.println` or use a logging API like log4j or the inbuilt logging API) in your code to check the state of various variables and identify running order of your code.

Add breakpoints in your code and use the debugger to step through your code and check the state of the various variables and logic of your code.

I "guess" that you are getting an exception because `board.getBoardElement(j, i).getImage()` is returning `null`, because you've load the image using something like `ImageIcon(String)`, but the image files are either maintained within the context of the Jar file or you've loaded them from a relative location off the disk and they are no longer accessible from the current Jars location

Start by making sure that your images are stored within the `src` directory of your Netbeans project, presumably in a subdirectly like `resources/images` or some such

Next, use `ImageIO.read` to load your images, this will throw an `IOException` if the image can't be loaded for some reason (other the failing silently like `ImageIcon`).  See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details.

Next, use `Class#getResource` to load the images...

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/images/NameOfImage.jpg"));
```

Comment: Oh God, I forgot change this in some of my class. Thanks for saving my time!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the jar file is contained in a directory named "dist" where as the root directory of executing through NetBeans is the upper directory of "dist". Hence any reference to file paths will be different depending on whether you execute the program from NetBeans or run the jar file.

Comment: Actually, I realized I haven't read your question carefully... My bad.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not mention the exact spot, which the stack trace would point to with a list of (source+line number+method), I assume it is:

```
g.drawImage(board.getBoardElement(j, i).getImage() ...
```

As MadProgrammer mentions, read the images with `Class.getResource` or `Class.getResourceAsStream`.
The path is relative to the class's package, or absolute `"/...."`. Important is that though file paths in Windows are case sensitive, under other operating systems and in jars they are case-sensitive.

Also call `g.dispose()`  after `createGraphics` resp. `getGraphics` (which is the same, with an older name).

```
Graphics g = bgg.getGraphics();
...
g.dispose();
```